# LazyColumn does not scroll if using TextFields as child

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, jetbrains-compose, compose-desktop

```
@Composable
fun init() {
    LazyColumn(Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
        for (i in 0..10) {
            item { Box(Modifier.padding(15.dp)) { TextField("Hallo$i", modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(), onValueChange = {}) } }
        }
    }
}
```

If i have something simple as this list with textfields
then the textfields will not let me scroll down the column.
Only works if i scroll down next to the textfields.
Tried also with readonly/disabled textfield.

is there a way to overcome this behaviour?
maybe a way to disable focus on textfield if scrolled?

I am using jetbrains-compose for desktop version (0.5.0-build245)
but can also be the same as in the jetpack-compose for android (did not try)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for the moment because i don't find any other solution i will use this workaround
using a invisible box above the text field and change the state accordingly

```
@Composable
fun init() {
    LazyColumn(Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
        for (i in 0..10) {
            item {
                val isfocused = remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
                val focusRequester = FocusRequester()
                Box(Modifier.padding(15.dp)) {
                    TextField("Hallo$i", modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth().focusRequester(focusRequester).onFocusChanged {
                        isfocused.value = it.isFocused
                    }, onValueChange = {})
                    if (!isfocused.value)
                        Box(
                            modifier = Modifier
                                .matchParentSize()
                                .alpha(0f)
                                .clickable(onClick = {
                                    isfocused.value = true
                                    focusRequester.requestFocus()
                                }),
                           )
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```